# Multi level JSON from CSV using Pig and JSONStorage

Tags: apache-pig

I have a CSV file of  the below format

```
customerid, period, credit, debit
 100, jan-2017, 500, 300
 100, jan-2017, 300,0
 100, feb-2017, 200,100
 100, mar-2017, 200,10
 200, jan-2017, 100, 200
 200, feb-2017,100,200
```

Now my requirement is to first group by customer id and then group by period and consolidate the transactions and create a hierarchical JSON as below using Apache Pig scripts.

```
    {
    {
        "customerid": 100,
        "periods": [{
            "period": "jan-2017",
            "transactions": [{"credit": 500,"debit": 300},....]
        }, {
            "period": "feb-2017",
            "transactions": [...]
        }, {
            "period": "mar-2017",
            "transactions": [....]
        }]
    }, {
        "customerid": 200,
        "periods": [{
            "period": "jan-2017",
            "transactions": [.....]
        }, {
            "period": "feb-2017",
            "transactions": [.....]
        }]
    }
}
```

I am fairly new to Pig but managed to write the below script

```
Data = LOAD 'data.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (
    company_id:chararray,
    period:chararray,
    debit:chararray,
    credit:chararray)

CompanyBag = GROUP Data BY (company_id);

final_trsnactionjson = FOREACH CompanyBag {
    ByCompanyId = FOREACH Data {
        PeriodBag = GROUP Data BY (period);

        IdPeriodItemRoot = FOREACH PeriodBag{
            ItemRecords = FOREACH Source GENERATE debit as debit, credit as credit
            GENERATE group as period, TOTUPLE(ItemRecords) as transactions;
        }   
    }
    GENERATE group as customerid, TOTUPLE(PeriodBag) AS periods;
};
```

But this is giving me the below error

```
mismatched input '{' expecting GENERATE
```

I searched a lot on how to generate nested Json using Pig, but could not find any good pointers. Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

1. Please use JsonLoader available in Pig.

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#jsonloadstore
you can provide nested schema in "AS"

2. Use com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') for simpler use for handling any nested JSON arrays.